# Merge duplicate array keys in a javascript array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

My Array :

```
{ { PID : [ '1' , '2' , '3' , ..] } , PID : [ '5' , '6' , '7' , '8' ....] , PID : .....} }
```

This one is a messy array and i would like to have my result combined and clean :

Result :

```
{ {PID : [ '1' , '2' , '3' , .. , '5' , '6' , '7' and so on ] }}
```

My Code (PSEUDO):

```
var links = [];

while( looping of a condition )
{

links.push( function(){

var xArr = [];
var yArr = [];
$.each(function(){
xArr.push(somevalue);
yArr.push(somevalue);
})

return { PID : xArr , SKU : yArr  } );

}
```

And this complex piece of code generated an array with multiple arrays under the duplicate keys 'PID'.

What I've tried:

1.Pushing xArr and yArr into zArr and returning that instead.

I dont have much idea how to proceed , i agree that i am not much of an expert in javascript arrays as of yet . I just ask for a way to go about this issue , more or less a pseudo explanation .

Comment: `[ ... ]` I like this note of mystery! What have you tried and why it did not worked? please read: [ask]

Comment: Your example object doesnt seem to make sense, can you take a look at it and make sure it is correct? Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: No one can help you without the expected result.

Comment: For the record thats not an array, but and object what has two arrays inside of it.

Comment: Also, this isn't really a question as much as it is a request for someone to code something for you.

Comment: Sorry for the mystery code , updated with more info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change that to array with objects you can use reduce

```js
var ar = [{PID: ['1', '2', '3', ]}, {PID: ['5', '6', '7', '8']}];

ar = ar.reduce(function(a, el) {
  a.PID = (a.PID || []).concat(el.PID);
  return a
}, {})

console.log(ar);
```

Comment: Wow man works great ! thanks a lot . If i may ask , can you explain this piece of code ?

Comment: You can learn all about it here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Answer (score 1):

The input element is wrong, I figured out something like based on [Reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```js
var arr = [ { PID : [ '1' , '2' , '3'] } , {PID : [ '5' , '6' , '7' , '8'] }];

var result = arr.reduce(function(previousValue, currentValue) {
  return {PID: previousValue.PID.concat(currentValue.PID)};
});

document.write(JSON.stringify(result, 4, 4));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man ! but Nenad Vracar's answer came first so i had to award him , in either case i couldnt grasp how this concept works . What exactly does the reduce function do ?